# when i running the procedure i got the error like "cannot insert NULL into ("BPMTEAM"."T_EMPLOYEE"."E_ID")" how to resolve

Tags: database, procedure, oracle12c

I want to create on procedure when i run the procedure i got below this error please guys how to resolve.

Error:

ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("BPMTEAM"."T_EMPLOYEE"."E_ID")
ORA-06512: at "BPMTEAM.PERSIST_EMPLOYEE_PROC", line 5
ORA-06512: at line 7

Procedure:

```html
create or replace PROCEDURE PERSIST_EMPLOYEE_PROC (EMP_XML XMLType)
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO T_EMPLOYEE (E_ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, PHONE)
VALUES
(
extractValue(EMP_XML, '/variable/id'),
extractValue(EMP_XML, '/variable/firstName'),
extractValue(EMP_XML, '/variable/lastName'),
extractValue(EMP_XML, '/variable/phone')
);

INSERT INTO AADDRESS (A_ID, ADDRESSLINE1, ADDRESSLINE2, CITY, STATE, ZIP, COUNTRY)
VALUES
(
extractValue(EMP_XML, '/variable/id'),
extractValue(EMP_XML, '/variable/address/addressLine1'),
extractValue(EMP_XML, '/variable/address/addressLine2'),
extractValue(EMP_XML, '/variable/address/city'),
extractValue(EMP_XML, '/variable/address/state'),
extractValue(EMP_XML, '/variable/address/zip'),
extractValue(EMP_XML, '/variable/address/country')
);
END;
```

Comment: What are you passing in to `EMP_XML` parameter?

Comment: It seems pretty clear that either the `id` component of `EMP_XML` is null (empty) or something else is wrong and it is passed in as if it was empty.